# Why does FFT fail to locate an Impulse in a Sine Wave?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, wavelet

I am performing some analysis on a sine wave, and I noticed something peculiar. When I introduced a single sample impulse randomly at any point in the sine frame, the FFT failed to locate it. Intuitively, an Impulse's FFT should be a Sine Wave, but I didn't get anything. In fact, I will say information was lost. Why is that the case?

[image]

To be absolutely clear about the code that generated this:

```
Fs=10e3; %Specify Sampling Frequency 
Ts=1/Fs; %Sampling period. 
Ns= 1024; %Number of time samples to be plotted. 
temp = Ts*(Ns-1);
t=[0:Ts:Ts*(Ns-1)]; %Make time array that contains Ns elements 
%t = [0, Ts, 2Ts, 3Ts,..., (Ns-1)Ts] 
f1= 60; 
f2=1000; 
f3=2000; 
f4=3200; 

x1=sin(2*pi*f1*t (1 : size(t, 2)/2)); %create sampled sinusoids at different frequencies 
x1(1, 400) = 5;
x2=cos(2*pi*f2*t (size(t, 2)/2 + 1: size(t, 2))) ; 

x = [x1 x2];

xfftmag=(abs(fft(x)));
xfftmagh=xfftmag(1:length(xfftmag)/2); 
%Plot only the first half of FFT, since second half is mirror imag 
%the first half represents the useful range of frequencies from 
%0 to Fs/2, the Nyquist sampling limit. 
f=[1:1:length(xfftmagh)]*Fs/Ns; %Make freq array that varies from 
%0 Hz to Fs/2 Hz. 


[ca, cd] = swt(x, 1, 'haar');
```

Comment: Your results look correct to me: an impulse will be evenly distributed in the frequency domain regardless of where it is in the time domain. What were you expecting?

Comment: I was actually expecting this but I wanted to know the theoretical reason behind this. I guess from what I understand is that the FFT of an impulse if a 1 as mentioned here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/delta/node6.html .

If that is the case, then Bjorn won't an impulse will be evenly distributed a tad wrong? I will be grateful for a response.

Comment: Skimming that link it looks like it only discusses the continuous version of the Fourier transform. In this case the DFT is a different beast: you must consider, among other things, the window function. (where "no" window is a rectangular window) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

Answer (score 3):

I thought an [impulse function](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/math/impulse.php) (aka [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)) would have *all* frequencies, not a single sine wave.

Perhaps we disagree on the meaning of impulse function.

[This reference](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~jiracek/DAGSAW/3.4.html) spells it out: a Dirac delta in the time domain is a constant function in the frequency domain.

It's a mathematical expression of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle: You can't know everything simultaneously in the time and frequency domains.

Your FFT might also be missing the impulse because of your choice of sampling rate. Try increasing the sampling rate and see if it captures the impulse.

Comment: Increasing the sampling, or increasing the size of the impulse should help (if by the 'sample impulse' the author means a rectangular impulse).

Comment: Duffymo, thanks for the response. Can you have a look at updated question? I made it a lot more clear with image.

Answer (score 0):

A pair of real (or complex conjugate) impulses at t and N-t will produce a cosine wave in the other domain.  The magnitude of a single unpaired impulse will be a constant, but the phase will rotate at the rate of some sinusoid depending on the position of the impulse. So you will need to look at the phase in the complex result, not just the magnitude, of an FFT to locate the impulse.

Looking at the magnitude alone and ignoring the phase information in the FFT result is what causes your loss of information.  Since the total area under an impulse may be relatively small, so will be that of the transform (low and spread out, perhaps buried in the noise.)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't plot the phase function.

If you look at that you should find a linear phase relationship (with wrap around at 2pi radians) that indicates how each of the constituent frequencies of the impulse (remember this is a discrete Fourier transform, so we have a discrete set of results) have slightly different phase delays - that is so they are all in synch at the impulse time point. Obviously there will nominally be two frequencies which have an independent dominant phase component, along with their side bands.

You may find the side-band components dominate, but a little bit of investigation with different amplitude components should help you see how the different parts add. You can also plot the amplitude/phase as a 3d helix, which can be illuminating for simple scenarios.